# Finding the globally shortest path in non-degenerate trapezoidations

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I'm searching for an efficient algorithm that finds the globally shortest path between two points in a 2-dimensional space with polygonal obstacles.

The source data is in the form of a non-degenerate vertical trapezoidation consisting of up to 10^4 trapezoids (non-degenerate meaning the lower and upper side of each trapezoid have at most 2 neighboring trapezoids each).

Running a shortest-path algorithm on the trapezoidation itself and then using a funnel algorithm does not guarantee finding the globally shortest path.

Computing the visibility graph of the corner vertices could potentially work, though I suspect this might use too much memory because the requirement for the algorithm is that it can be used frequently (about 100 times a second) on a server with multiple (up to 700) maps in memory, but feel free to correct me if you think that is not an issue!

To visualize what the data looks like, I uploaded the triangulation of a small map, you can click the image to view it as a SVG.

[image: Example].

Comment: The shortest path is composed of straight segments going from border point to border point (apart from the segment from the starting point and the segment to the destination if they are not border points). So the visibility graph of all border points should give you the shortest path.

Comment: Yes, I considered that in the question, but it seems to me that this would take a rather large amount of memory.

Comment: I start to see the point... with 10^4 trapezoids one has roughly 2*10^4 points (each of which can be represented by a 16 bit integer, i.e. 2 bytes) leading to 4*10^8 edges in the worst case meaning 800 MBytes for one of the 700 maps alone...

Comment: On the other hand, there are edges on the visibility graph which will never be used such as those going from one border to the opposite one in a certain regions (to be defined better...)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a graph with

1) vertices at all of the vertices of the trapezoids in addition to the source and destination points.

2) edges between any 2 of these vertices if they are line of sight with respect to each other and with edge weight equal to the distance between the 2 vertices.

Then this problem seems exactly like the shortest distance between 2 points in a graph problem, which has many well known solutions ([Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) etc.)

Comment: A* is probably more efficient than Dijkstra